# Javascript HTTP POST with JSON data

Tags: javascript, http, post

Can I send a request as below? With parameters being assigned with a JSON style object. I only get error. But when I use a REST client and choose RAW data, it's OK. I guess I must have written incorrect code. How to send raw JSON data in JavaScript? Could anyone help me?

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://someURL";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
var parameters = {
    "username": "myname",
    "password": "mypass"
};
// Neither was accepted when I set with parameters="username=myname"+"&password=mypass" as the server may not accept that
xmlhttp.send(parameters);
```

Comment: By "JASON", do you mean "JSON"?

Comment: @ajp15243 obviously...

Comment: You need to convert it to a string `JSON.stringify`, encode it, and post it.

Comment: FYI, that's not a "JSON style" object, nor is it JSON data. It's an object literal that creates an object.

Comment: inspect your traffic using the browser console to see what's getting sent.

Answer (score 22):

No. The [`send()` method can take a number of different argument types](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method), but a plain object is not one of them (so it will probably end up having `toString()` being called on it and being turned into `"[Object object]"`).

If you want to send JSON then you must:

1. Say you are sending JSON: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`
2. Convert your JavaScript object to a string of JSON text: `var parameters = JSON.stringify({"username":"myname","password":"mypass"});`
3. Be prepared to accept JSON instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded data on the server side.

---

Also note that, since you are using an *absolute* URI, you may run into [cross domain issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", AjaxURL, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
cb(xmlhttp.responseText);               
}
};
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(Idata));
```